# java utf-8 text file reading bug?

Tags: java, file-io, utf-8

well I have a simple text file where I have my textual data filled, which requires to be saved as utf-8, since I have some unicode symbols...

Well i just wrote a normal text file with notepad and saved as txt with utf-8

But i seem to be getting some kind of weird thing in front:
[image]

It's some kind of weird dot which can't even normally be pasted anywhere else.
I could maybe try removing the first symbol, but I don't think that's a real solution, besides I'm not sure if it will always come up...

This is the code part:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String values;

        //Read File Line By Line

        System.out.println("Generating queries from: " + fileName);
        String fields = br.readLine(); 
        System.out.println("The fields are: " + fields);
```

Anyone came accross this and knows a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry i should have marked it red, it's right at the line where: the fields are: XLanguage_code... That's the X from here

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just a screen artifact? Something that doesn't affect the code, but is just left there?

Comment: What is the value of `fields.codePointAt(0)`?

Comment: Yeah, i'm pretty sure it's not a screen artifact.

Comment: probably should add, that it's not only notepad, it happened to me earlier today when my notepad++ was saving a txt file with unicode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably a [Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  Some text editors (on Windows) start a UTF-8 text file with a BOM to flag that it is Unicode.

If you need to deal with this in Java, test to see if the first Unicode codepoint you read from the file is `0xffef`, and if it is then remove it.

Comment: I agree.  Utf-8 is byte order independent, but Microsoft adds one any way as an indicator that the file is utf-8.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8

Comment: It's **definitely** a BOM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467241/java-utf-8-text-file-reading-bug#comment13520566_10467241 (`0d65279 = 0xFEFF`)